# "Select -skip" doesn't skip the very first line

Tags: powershell, csv, select, skip, import-csv

I need to skip the first 4 lines of a csv, because line 5 includes the headers:

```
1 Assetliste;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
2 Firma: Ospelt  Gruppe;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3 Abrufdatum: 19.02.2018 23:06;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
4 User:;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
5 Header1; Header2 and so on.....
```

I use following PowerShell Code to Import and Export the file in the Format i need

```
$ImportedCSV = Import-CSV "$($importPath)\$($name.name)" -Delimiter ';' | Select -skip 4 
$ImportedCSV | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File ("$($importPath)\$($name.name)")
```

**But it doesn't skip the very first line which results in following Output:**

```
1 Assetliste
2 Develop
3 Develop
4 Kyocera
5 Kyocera
```

If I delete the 4 lines manually and not using "select skip", my script works as planned:

```
1 Marke,Modell,ArtikelNr, ...
2 Develop,ineo+ 308,A7PY121, ...
3 Develop,ineo 284e,A61G121, ...
4 Kyocera,FS-4200DN,FS-4200DN, ...
5 and so on.....
```

Comment: Try replacing the first `Import-Csv` with `Get-Content`.

Comment: Doesn't work, if i use get-content the Output i weird, first line: "PSPath,PSParentPath,PSChildName,PSDrive,PSProvider,ReadCount,Length,Datum"

Answer (score 1):

Given your case (which is a little odd), you can do the following:

```
$csv = Get-Content -Path "$importpath\$($name.name)" | Select-Object -Skip 4
$csv = $csv | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
$csv | Export-Csv -Path "$importpath\$($name.name)" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

You have to remove the offending lines *before* the conversion takes place.

Answer (score 0):

`Import-Csv` expects the first line to be the header. Use `Get-Content` instead.

```
$ImportedCSV = Get-Content "$($importPath)\$($name.name)" -Delimiter ';' | Select -skip 4
```